# find html attributes containing apostrophes using regex (notepad++)

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

**Solved (see first comment by "justhalf")**

**

I know, using RegEx for messing with HTML is evil.

However, my means and know-how are restricted, and I don't know what else to do.

The situation is as follows:

I have a website containing some 5000 pages.

There are some errors I would like to fix:

Things like this:
`<a href="foo" alt='The queen's attendants ate the cake.' id='yee'>`

The error in this example is that the value for the HTML attribute "alt" is enclosed in apostrophes, yet the text contains an apostrophe as well.
There should be many errors of this type. I want to find them all and correct them.

I tried it with this pattern: `{ [a-zA-Z].*?='[^'].*?'[^=>].*?'}`:

That is: a space, followed by the name of the HTML attribute `([a-zA-Z].*?)`, followed by = and the attribute's value `(='[^'].*?')`. Up until here, this should match a valid HTML attribute.
For a valid HTML attribute, what would follow now from here would be either a space followed by the next attribute, or the closing bracket > for the HTML tag.
So, in order to match erroneous HTML attributes as described above, I continue the search pattern with `([^=>].*?')`, that is, a string which does not contain = or >, followed by a '. In other words, the next apostrophe is expected *before* any = or > sign.

According to my understanding, this **should** exclude valid HTML attributes, which are followed by the next HTML attribute or the closing > for the HTML tag. **But somehow it does not really work like that.**

With this search pattern, for example, I find things like this:

```
class='noteTag' href='

id='fnt-14' name='
```

So... valid HTML attributes, followed by the next.

But I thought these things should be excluded by `[^=>].*?'`

Very confused.

Comment: You should remove the dots, you don't mean it. You should be using `[a-zA-Z]*?='[^']*?'[^=>]*?'`. Because when you do `[^=>].*?` you will match anything that doesn't start with `=` or `>`, since `.*?` will match any string. Note that `[a-z]+`, for example, will match any string consisting of only lower case alphabets, while `[a-z].+` will match any string that starts with a lowercase alphabet.

Comment: Note `[a-zA-Z]*?='[^']*?'[^=>]*?'` will fail on text with multiple single quotes like `alt='The queens''' attendants ate the cake.'`. You could try to use `[a-zA-Z]*?='[^']*'[^=>]*'` instead to solve this problem.

Comment: @IvanChau: Thank you very much!
Slowly I'm getting a feel for all these modifiers and their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting @justhalf answer:

Regex `[a-zA-Z]*?='[^']*'[^=>]*'` can be used to accommodate these patterns:

```
<a href="foo" alt='The queen's attendants ate the cake.' id='yee'>
<a href="foo" alt='The queens''' attendants ate the cake.' id='yee'>
<a href="foo" alt='The queen's attendants ate the cake.' >
<a href="foo" alt='The queen's attendants ate the cake.'>
<a href="foo" id='yee' alt='The queen's attendants ate the cake.'>
```

Note multiple single quotes can be tackled as well.
See [@justhalf comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942621/find-html-attributes-containing-apostrophes-using-regex-notepad#comment31452387_20942621) for explanation.